# Do I have a blown Head Gaskett or Bad Radiator?

Tags: nissan

Two weeks ago I was on my way to work in my 1992 Nissan D21.I noticed I wasn't getting the full power when I stepped on the accelerator. A few minutes Later I head a loud pop then, the biggest cloud of white steam started coming out of my engine. I pulled over tried to start the truck, looked under the hood and the engine was covered with coolant and it wouldn't start. Then after work that day the truck started up and I moved it. I have been able to drive it around since with no problem, except, the thermostat isn't reading the temperature.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't sound like a head gasket....Check the Engine via the Oil filler hole for signs of water...Any white sludge and your head gasket is gone.

However, if its not the head gasket, sounds like your cooling system is blocked or constricted and /or your temperature gauge is not working.  You could have gunk clogging the system anywhere in the Engine cooling network including the radiator - but the radiator is usually obvious.  Can you see the water flow with the rad. cap off when the Engine is hot?  If not - something is blocked - perhaps a hose but more likely in the head somewhere.

Can you get a cooling system flush by experts?  Not too expensive....

(NB:  No temperature reading is also a sign of NO water)

Comment: Thanks for all that valuable information. A blocked hose makes sense, the day before this happened I changed the oil myself and The oil filter going in was quite a bit bigger than the one I took out so It could have put some pressure on a hose or something. I'll check that stuff tonight and report back.

Comment: So I recently went and drove the nissan around again and it was fine for about 15 minutes then started to heat up and smoke from the engine block. I also heard a rattling later into the 15 minute drive

Comment: Hmmm, rattling could be many things...Water pump broken, Valves bouncing, steel fractures in the head / block, loose timing chain.  Sounds like a pressure test for the water system is the first thing I would check... (Unless you want to start taking apart the engine)

Comment: ...I mean ANYTHING could be wrong...Timing could be WAY off, ....etc  Hard to say without comprehensive history.  Process of elimination, listen to the rattling when idling with the bonnet up.  Don't let the engine over heat

Comment: I would guess a valve (stem) seal has broken...Which could destory your cooling system too, by letting the compression into the cooling system

Comment: Hey Sorry for the late reply! It was a blown head gasket and some sort of seal in the back of the engine. Also had a warped head. All in all it costed 760$